# recursion and function call in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
function test(param, n) {
  console.log(param, "start --- ", n);

  if (n > 1) {
    console.log(param, "before first recursion --- ", n);

    test("test-1", n - 1);
    console.log(param, "after first recursion --- ", n);

    test("test-2", n - 1);
    console.log(param, "after second recursion --- ", n);
  }

  console.log(param, "end --- ", n);
}

test("initialize", 3);
```

In output console

**test-1 after first recursion ---** I am getting value **2**, can someone please explain the flow of code is going as, I was expecting **3** as the output, because in my understanding if the **test("test-1", n-1)** is completed then the next call i.e. **test("test-2", n-1)** will be getting **3** value as fresh input, also is the js working synchronous here ?

Comment: It's fully synchronous. It's just executing the recursion before continuing.

Comment: Your output should be:  initialize start --- 3, initialize, before first recursion --- 3, test-1  start --- 2, test-1 before first recursion --- 2, test-1 after first recursion --- 2, test-2 start --- 1, test-2, end --- 1

Answer (score 2):

You could use some indentations to the output and look which level is actually running.

```js
function test(param, n, level = 0) {
    console.log(''.padStart(level * 2), level, param, "start --- ", n);
    if (n > 1) {
        test("test-1", n - 1, level + 1);
        test("test-2", n - 1, level + 1);
    }
    console.log(''.padStart(level * 2), level, param, "end --- ", n);
}

test("initialize", 3);
```